# Extracting file name from the file path in C#?

Tags: c#, filenames, filepath

I've seen a couple similar questions but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.
I have a list box where I want all selected test files to be listed without the whole path. With this current code, no text is being entered into the list box. Where am I going wrong?

```
if (cmdBrowse.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    string testNameShort = Path.GetFileName(listboxTestsToRun.Text.ToString());
    listboxTestsToRun.Items.Add(testNameShort);
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What kind of control is cmdBrowse?

Comment: FolderBrowser or OpenFileDialog?

Comment: Did you debug it what are you seeing? I don't think listboxTestsToRun.Text.ToString() does what you think it does.

Comment: If I'm not wrong, are you retrieving the value of the `listboxTestsToRun.Text` ListBox, extracting the filename with `Path` class and inserting it into the same ListBox? Is there any value on the `listboxTestsToRun` variable when you debug your code?

Comment: Are you sure there's an item selected? Also, even if there was, this code would take the selected item, get the filename part, and add it to the end of the listbox items (leaving the original filename still in the list). That doesn't sound like something you'd want to do.

Comment: Sorry, that is the title of the browse dialog.

    OpenFileDialog cmdBrowse = new OpenFileDialog();
            cmdBrowse.Title = "Add a test to the test queue";
            cmdBrowse.Filter = ".cmd Files|*.cmd";
            cmdBrowse.InitialDirectory = @"Start path";

Answer (score 8, accepted):

<strike>Supposing that</strike> cmdBrowse is an OpenFileDialog and you want the filename selected by your user to be added to the listbox. In this case you code this

```
if (cmdBrowse.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
   if(cmdBrowse.FileName.Length > 0)
   {
      string testNameShort = Path.GetFileName(cmdBrowse.FileName);
      listboxTestsToRun.Items.Add(testNameShort);
   }
}
```

Comment: Worked exactly as I wanted it to, thanks!

I also now see what I did wrong there. I was drawing my path from what was IN the list box as opposed to the file I was selecting from the dialog.
Love this site. Thanks Steve!

Comment: Oh well, (depending on what the OP wants to do) probably the OP should also add `cmdBrowse.CheckFileExists=true`; but I don't know if it is required

Answer (score 1):

If `cmdBrowse` is an [`OpenFileDialog`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog.aspx), then, unless you're expecting something else meaningful from the listbox, you'll need to work with the path that the user has selected (which is what I suspect you're trying to do), such as:

```
var fileName = Path.GetFileName(cmdBrowse.FileName);
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at performing a Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(FilePath) method on your paths being retrieved to begin with, then adding them to the box